# How can we remove adSense ads from post content

Tags: adsense

How can i remove the adsense banners from post content of wordpress site.
It seems ads adding automatically.
http://www.digitaldevnet.com/power-of-influencer-marketing-to-your-business/
showing at 3 different places.
I am not using any plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can target it by class 'adsbygoogle' and remove it from the document like this:

```
var ads = document.querySelector('.adsbygoogle')
ads.parentNode.removeChild(ads)
```

If you need to remove all ads from the page you'd need to get a collection of all elements with this class and remove the within the loop

```
var ads = document.querySelectorAll('.adsbygoogle')
for (var i=0; i<ads.length; i++)
  ads[i].parentNode.removeChild(ads[i])
```

But I believe there will be one banner from amazon left...

If your site is not hosted on free hosting services you can just remove widgets with ads from your template.